# Is there a caseinsensitive version of strrchr and wcsrchr?(c++)

Tags: c++, strrchr

I try to check if `variable` ends with `expression`.

My current code is this:

`(strchr(variable.data(), tolower(expression[0])) || strchr(variable.data(), toupper(expression[0]))) && _stricmp((strrchr(variable.data(), tolower(expression[0]))? strrchr(variable.data(), tolower(expression[0])) : strrchr(variable.data(), toupper(expression[0]))), expression.data()) == 0`

It works. But with a case-insensitive version of `strrchr` and `strchr` I can simlpify it.
I also need the case-insensitive versions of `wcsrchr` and `wcsrchr` for UTF16-strings:

`(wcschr(variable.data(), tolower(expression[0])) || wcschr(variable.data(), toupper(expression[0]))) && _wcsicmp((wcsrchr(variable.data(), tolower(expression[0])) ? wcsrchr(variable.data(), tolower(expression[0])) : wcsrchr(variable.data(), toupper(expression[0]))), expression.data()) == 0`

I´m open for other simplifications.

I can´t write additional methods because the mainprogram is a vs-extension written in c#.

Comment: Your expression would be simplified if both the variable and expression were converted to the same case first. However, you could consider constructing a regular expression match and specify matching to be case insensitive. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex

Comment: such a long line is terrible. No one likes horizontal scrolling. Cut it short also helps readability

Comment: @jxh You should be aware, that std::regex is extremely slow, compared to almost any other regex library.  Converting both expressions to the same case will be much, much faster.

Comment: @Kaznov Was not aware the C++ regex library was its own implementation. I would have though it would be wrapped around existing POSIX regex library APIs, which themselves could be replaced with alternative implementations.